# java.util.Random makes 100 times faster computation?

Tags: java, benchmarking

I am totally lost for words, i have no idea what's going on...

```
//import java.util.Random;

public class TestInProgress {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start, end;
        long average;

//      Random random= new Random();

    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {

        average= 0L;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {

            start= System.nanoTime();
                double temp= fastComputeSigm(0.0);
            end= System.nanoTime();
            average+= (end - start);
        }

        average= average/ 100L;
        System.out.println("AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: "+average);

        average= 0L;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {

            start= System.nanoTime();
                double temp= Math.exp(0.0)/(1.0 + Math.exp(0.0));
            end= System.nanoTime();

            average+= (end - start);
        }

        average= average / 100L;
        System.out.println("AVERAGE SIGMOID: "+average);
    }
}

static double fastComputeSigm(double value) {
    return 0.0;
}
```

}

The most surprising is the output:

> AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 98 **AVERAGE SIGMOID:** **38625** AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE:
>   106 AVERAGE SIGMOID: 65 AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 299 AVERAGE SIGMOID: 201
>   AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 36 AVERAGE SIGMOID: 65 AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 53
>   AVERAGE SIGMOID: 57

see that? I uncommented Random (and its import)
What would you expect? output:

> AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 90 **AVERAGE SIGMOID: 324** AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 131
>   AVERAGE SIGMOID: 73 AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 217 AVERAGE SIGMOID: 36
>   AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 53 AVERAGE SIGMOID: 12 AVERAGE FASTCOMPUTE: 53
>   AVERAGE SIGMOID: 69

I tried this on eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
I'm using java 10.0.2
My computer has a Intel Core i5-7300HQ
with those cache memories : L1 256, L2 1024, L3 6M
I run on windows 10

note: I tried to make the forloop with j<1,2,3,... several times no helping **the first sigmoid** always has absurd time length

edit: tried launching it with windows commandline (javac and java), same result

Comment: Writing Java benchmarks correctly is difficult due to things like the Just In Time compiler. Use a proper benchmarking tool - see the link in the first comment.

Comment: I will look into that thanks

Comment: Removed the eclipse label - this is reproducible with Java 8 / macOS / i7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general comments pointing you at the trickiness of micro-benchmarking are correct and you should be using JMH. In this particular case it looks like your timing / benchmarking code introduces latency that wasn't there in the first place.

Here is a compacted version of your code that demonstrates that the issue is triggered not by the use of `Random` but of the use of `System.nanoTime()` (which `Random()` calls internally)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start, end, average;
    double temp = 0;

    // start = System.nanoTime();

    average = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        start = System.nanoTime();
        temp += Math.exp(0.0) / (1.0 + Math.exp(0.0));
        end = System.nanoTime();

        average += (end - start);
        // System.out.println(i + " " + (end - start));
    }
    System.out.println("AVERAGE: " + (average / 100));
    System.out.println("temp: " + temp);
}
```

When I uncomment `start = System.nanoTime()` I observer about x100 speedup - at this point it is important to remember that the units here are `nanoseconds` so we are *very* sensitive to whatever it is the runtime is doing in the background. If you uncomment  `System.out.println(i + " " + (end - start));` you will see an occasional *hiccup* that is responsible for the entire slowdown. While it may be interesting to chase the reason for that *hiccup* the following version of the code indicates that it is due to the measurement rather than the core functionality so you may want to make sure that this is something you want to spend your own time on [1]:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double temp = 0;

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        temp += Math.exp(0.0) / (1.0 + Math.exp(0.0));
    }

    System.out.println("AVERAGE: " + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 100));
    System.out.println("temp: " + temp);
}
```

The AVERAGE values here are similar to the previous version with `start = System.nanoTime()` uncommented.

[1] If you are interested in digging deeper into this particular behavior, try timing your test while running with the `-Xint` VM option which disables the compiler.

Comment: **CODE 1:** Whether I uncomment or not `long start= System.nanoTime()`, the average  doesn't change, but yeah println(string) does adds an extra.

**CODE 2:** Strangely enough this version that I thought more compact gives me 2-4 times bigger result.

code1: (without println)`AVERAGE: 18x-24x temp: 50.0`code2 and code1 with println: `AVERAGE: 4xx-8xx temp: 50.0`

Comment: So what I just showed kinda contradict your statement "the code indicates that it is due to the measurement rather than the core functionality". Nonetheless it doesn't take away that my micro-benchmark isn't on point.